# SP2013: User Profile Synchronization Service wants a password, but SharePoint manages that one

Tags: user-profile-service

My User Profile Synchronization Service won't start.  When I go to Central Administration > Manage services on server and try to start the service, it asks me for the password for my farm account.

Well, I'd love to type that in, but SharePoint manages that password for me, resetting it monthly.

I read about the `Repair-SPManagedAccountDeployment` cmdlet, but I'm not sure if that's what I need or not.  All other services are running fine.

Is there any way I can tell SharePoint to give itself the password and start that service?  If not, what should I do?

Comment: is it stop after every password change? why you need to change it every month?

Comment: SharePoint managed accounts change their password monthly, and the farm is updated with the new credentials.  This doesn't usually happen, but for some reason, UPSS didn't get the new credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Every month seems extreme, but either way you have to realize that depending on your farm there are as many as 5 different accounts that cannot be managed and 3 important ones that have to be changed through the UI or PowerShell if you change the passwords.

For your question about the User Profile Sync Service, just stop the service and when you restart it, supply the correct credentials.

You may also have to reset your import connection account and your search crawl account. These 3 are the most common.

Comment: That's the thing:  the SharePoint farm account has its password managed by SharePoint.  I don't know what it is anymore.  Would I have to stop the entire farm, reset the password by hand, then type it in everywhere it's needed?  Or, is there some command to "re-sync" the UPSS credentials?

Comment: In Central Admin under Security you can reset the farm credentials to a known value. Then, once the farm is back up, you can return to the UPS and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing managed Account password every month, practically not good as per my experience.We had the plan to change the password once a year. Changing every month means you have a down time for your service applications.

I am not in favor of changing password from SharePoint, rather change it by yourself. change the password and then update SharePoint with new password.

Their is no automated way to update Password for UPAsync, only choice is do it manually and change your strategy for password change.

Here is very good guide on it.

[Changing SharePoint 2010’s Service Account Passwords](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=301)